# onclick client event handler in <p:commandButton> causes resubmit of page

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have strange problem with following code:-

```
        <p:dataTable id="dataTbl_mnuItmList_id" rows="5"
                paginator="true" paginatorPosition="top"
                value="#{addMenuItemMB.menuItemList}" var="menuItem"
                style="width:100%; height:100%">
                <p:column headerText="Item Name" sortBy="itemName">
                    <h:outputText value="#{menuItem.itemName}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Created Date" sortBy="createdDate">
                    <h:outputText value="#{menuItem.createdDate}">
                    </h:outputText>
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Modified Date" sortBy="modifiedDate">
                    <h:outputText value="#{menuItem.modifiedDate}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column>
                    <p:commandButton id="cmdBtn_edit"
                        onclick="widVar_menuItem.unselectAllRows()"
                        update=":frm_addMnuItm_dlg:outPutPnl_addMnuItmDlg_id"
                        oncomplete="PF('dlg_addMnuItem_widVar').show()"
                        icon="ui-icon-pencil" title="Edit" value="Edit">
                        <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{menuItem}"
                            target="#{addMenuItemMB.menuItemToEdit}" />
                    </p:commandButton>
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
```

Following is the dataTable having **widgetVar="widVar_menuItem"**

```
        <p:dataTable id="dataTbl_menuItem_id" rows="5"
            paginator="true" paginatorPosition="top"
            widgetVar="widVar_menuItem" editable="true" editMode="cell"
            value="#{addMenuItemMB.mnuItmSpecDtlListModel}"
            var="mnuItmSpecDtl" rowKey="#{mnuItmSpecDtl.id}"
            selection="#{addMenuItemMB.selectedLabels}">
            <f:facet name="header">
                <p:outputLabel value="Specification Label" />
            </f:facet>
            <p:column selectionMode="multiple"
                style="width:2%; display:none;" />

            <p:ajax event="toggleSelect"
                listener="#{addMenuItemMB.onToggleSelect}" />
            <p:ajax event="cellEdit"
                listener="#{addMenuItemMB.onCellEdit}" />
            <p:column headerText="Label" style="width:31%">
                <h:outputText value="#{mnuItmSpecDtl.labelName}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Price" style="width:25%">
                <p:cellEditor>
                    <f:facet name="output">
                        <h:outputText value="#{mnuItmSpecDtl.price}" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="input">
                        <p:inputText value="#{mnuItmSpecDtl.price}"
                            style="width:50px" />
                    </f:facet>
                </p:cellEditor>
            </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
```

Above code Having command button in datatable column which has the property **f:setPropertyActionListener** it is working fine. But when I added **onclick** client event handler the page get submitted and when I remove onclick attribute from command button it is working fine as expected. So my question is what is wrong with above code, or What I realized (it may be wrong) client side event handler are not property working with **f:setPropertyActionListener** attribute. 
Please suggest me proper solution.

Thanks.

Comment: So, you don't want to submit the page when the button is clicked, but keeping the onclick event?

Comment: yes Pellizon you understood right.

Comment: would you update your post with the code of widVar_menuItem.unselectAllRows() ? or menuItem is what ?

Comment: Hello Hatem I have update the code with widVar_menuItem